# how can i make Html. Begin Form() work using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hello i am  developing a web site using MVC in order to insert data into my data base i created method called `chekout` like below in my `HomeController`:

```
public ActionResult chekout()
        {

            return View(Tuple.Create<Commande,IEnumerable< Panier >, LoginViewModel> (new Commande(), db.Paniers.ToList(), new LoginViewModel()));

        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult chekout([Bind(Include = "prenom,nom,Adresse,telephone,cart")] Commande commande)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    commande.Id_commande = db.Commandes.Max().Id_commande + 1;

                    var panier = from Panier in db.Paniers
                                 select Panier;
                    var userEmail = this.User.Identity.Name;
                    panier = panier.Where(x => x.user.Contains(userEmail));
                    foreach (var item in panier)
                    {
                        commande.produit = item.Quantite + " X " + item.nom_produit;
                        commande.prix = int.Parse(item.prix) * item.Quantite;
                        commande.Email = userEmail;
                        db.Commandes.Add(commande);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("order_complete", "Home");

                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("chekout", "Home");

                }

            }
```

then i created the form in the view `chekout` like this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("chekout", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                             <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.prenom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.prenom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.prenom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.nom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.nom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.nom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.Adresse, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.Adresse, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.Adresse, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.telephone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.telephone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.telephone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.cart, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item1.cart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "veuillez remplir ce champ" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item1.cart, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Commander" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
}
```

[image]
this is my page after i insert my data i click on commander it suppose to insert data into my database then move on the order_complete page but it id not it wipe up my data an redirect to the same page like this 
[image]

but it did not work and i can not know why when i click on the button it take me back redirect to the same page without inserting data to my database
i would be grateful if anyone can help me

Comment: i am not changing them i am setting them : some of the parameters are taking from the form and the others are set up automatically

Comment: not working same problem

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? You need to be more specific about your problem. Put a break-point in your method and tell us what you see!

Comment: i get no error no result nothing just the page redirect to the same page nothing happens

Comment: Because you have already said: it will be redirected to the same page by this line `return RedirectToAction("chekout", "Home");` in your catch block. Remove your `try-catch` block temporarily and see where is your Error.

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure the `chekout` method is called!?

Comment: yes because i tried to change this line else  return RedirectToAction("chekout", "Home"); to  else return RedirectToAction("shop","Home"); it  redirect to shop page so i guess the problem in   if (ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: So as I said already put a breakpoint on your method and go through your code to see what happens exactly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017

Comment: yeah it returns false

Comment: it is shown that all attributes are null

Comment: nothing same problem

Comment: For passing data from view to controller you need the same model in controller `model => model.Item1`  here you are passing the `Item1` model but you haven't provided the model name in controller lilke :  `public ActionResult chekout(Item1 objItemModel)` controller is expecting the same model